# Show that $f\in A_{n-1}(V)$ or $f\in A_n(V)$ is decomposable (Tensors, or k-linear forms)

Tags: linear-algebra, manifolds

Show that $f\in A_{n-1}(V)$ or $f\in A_n(V)$ is decomposable.

$f\in A_k(V)$ is decomposable if there exists a $a_1,...,a_k\in V^\wedge$ such that $f=a_1\wedge...\wedge a_k$

In this case "let $n=dim(V)$" and the -1 follows.

I have seen many pages from this site before and I know that it is almost required of me to show what I have done, unfortunately in this case I have done nothing, I am not sure how to approach this at all, it is my first question on decomposing tensors.

I do however know it to be true (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Decomposable.html is the most recent tab) but I'm on page 10 of search-engine results, so I finally registered.

Thanks

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: @hjhjhj57 to show that any $f\in A_{n-1}(V)$ or $f\in A_n(V)$ is decomposable. (See the link: the line "where alpha ^ beta denotes a wedge product. Forms of degree 0, 1, dimV-1, and dimV are always decomposable. " - to show this!)

Comment: but that's not true in general. For example, in a 4 dimensional space $e_1\wedge e_2 + e_3\wedge e_4$ isn't decomposable. Am I missing something?

Comment: @hjhjhj57 it says "dim(V)-1 and dim(V) are always decomposable" - that.

Comment: Yes, you should edit the question to clarify everything.

Comment: @hjhjhj57 I'm not sure what you mean, what would you have me add? Also can you help.

Comment: "Let $n=dim V$"

Comment: @hjhjhj57 it should involve projections, but I'm still unsure, can you help?

Comment: @hjhjhj57 sorry for the MANY MANY comments, this was downvoted? How could I have prevented that?

Comment: I'm not sure why it was downvoted, if you're not sure what to do then... at least you are open, however long drawn out comments are not good, if @hjhjhj57 can help I'm sure he will.

Comment: http://physics.oregonstate.edu/coursewikis/GDF/book/gdf/decomp related?

Answer (score 2):

One case is trivial, since $A_n V$ is a one dimensional space, every vector in it is of the form $a e_1\wedge\cdots\wedge e_n$, which is decomposable.

I've been thinking about the other case and I think you could prove it using the isomorphism between $A_1$ and $A_{n-1}$ (choose a base for $V = A_1 V$ and define a linear function in the natural way for the basis), but I'm not sure yet. I'll edit as soon as I know the right answer.

EDIT1: Consider a basis $\{e_i\}$ of $V$, then we can define an isomorphism between $A_1 V$ and $A_{n-1}V$ by $f(e_i)=e_1\wedge\cdots\wedge \hat{e}_i\wedge\cdots\wedge e_n$ (the hat means you remove that element from the product), and extending it linearly (this is equivalent to using the Hodge star operator suggested in the link provided in the comments).

Then, taking its inverse, $g$, and considering an arbitrary element of $\eta\in A_{n-1}V$,
$$
\eta = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k e_1\wedge\cdots\wedge \hat{e}_k\wedge\cdots\wedge e_n,
$$
we have that $g(\eta) = \sum_{k=1}^n a_ke_k := v_1$. We can then extend $v_!$ to a whole basis of $V$, $\{v_i\}$. The next part consist of showing that $f(v_1) = K v_2\wedge\cdots\wedge v_n$ for some constant $K$, which should require some work.

Note: There are different ways to approach this subject, so if you're thinking about antisymmetric multilinear functions, whenever I talk about a basis o $V$ think about it's dual basis.

Comment: The elements of $A_n(V)$ are (linear) functions of the form: $f:V^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, I wouldn'd consider it shown now, could you expand on that please?

Comment: Hey, your answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/963004/find-a-basis-mathcalb-of-mathbbr2-that-diagonalizes-a-reflection/979141#979141 I've upvoted it, I think the person downvoted because you didn't do the work for them, you don't write T as a diag. matrix, but you've answered the question so an upvote from me! (I can't comment there yet)

Comment: I appreciate the upvotes but that's not how this works. Upvotes are anonymous so users are free to use them as they please, in particular, not to bargain with them. I've been thinking about your question since I first commented on it, but there are some affairs I need to take care of before I can continue thinking of it. I invite you to un-upvote my other replies and just ask for the things that aren't clear. In the end we are all here to help and get help.

Comment: I don't understand? I'm siding with you, those downvotes were unjust (the wedge one and divergence one I have not touched because I don't understand fully) but these two, you give a right answer! I love the combinations one, it's an elegant solution! I'm not trying to bargain...?

Comment: Now, as for the question on-topic, a multilinear transformation is defined by it's value on the basis of each space of its domain. So, since we are dealing with antisymmetric multilinear functions, the $f$ you mention is defined by its values in the basis, and any other multilinear transformation will be a scalar multiple of it. Try showing it!

Comment: I'm certainly trying, I'm just not entirely sure what I am dealing with! I have no notes on this subject!